# Randomly sample grid using coordinates

Tags: r

I have a numbered grid (19 x 22) laid over an image and I need to randomly select 250 of the 418 Frames. Is there a way I can do this by randomly selecting an x and y coordinates without having any duplicates?

Thanks

[Example of grid over image (rows and columns are not labeled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMjfK.jpg)

Comment: Is your "grid" a matrix?

Comment: Provide an example of your dataset. You can learn more about creating an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way of generating random X and Y values without repeats that are in your grid.

```
library(tidyverse) # Gives us both %>% and filter_n

# Create a dataframe (technically a tibble) with one cell for each
# cell in your grid
combos <- expand.grid(x = seq(1, 19, 1), y = seq(1, 22, 1)) %>%
  tbl_df()

# Draw 250 random samples from the data without replacement
# If you post more information about the data you're using,
# I might be able to skip the creation of the combos data entirely
grid_sample <- sample_n(combos, size = 250, replace = FALSE)
```

If you post a code example of the data type you want to sample, I might be able to simplify.